# Can I install MaaS on the same server my nodes will be on?

Tags: juju, cloud, maas

Hello every geek and nerds out there.

I'm a network engineer but I've been following Ubuntu and the Cloud architecture for quite a while now.

Question:
I have a HP DL380 Dual Quad Core with 16GB of RAM and eight 73GB HDDs. My intention is to install MAAS on this server and use the same server to host some OS (eg. Linux, Win) by using some hard drives as server nodes for these OSs.

Please could you shed more light on this. Am I mis-understanding what MAAS does or how it should be installed.

Do I need a seperate server for MAAS? Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need separate server for MAAS. You can share MAAS services:

> maas - seed cloud setup, which includes both the region controller and the cluster controller below.
>
> maas-region-controller - includes the web UI, API and database.
>
> maas-cluster-controller - controls a group (“cluster”) of nodes including DHCP management.
>
> maas-dhcp/maas-dns - required when managing dhcp/dns.

with KVM or VirtualBox for other OS.

[Installing MAAS](http://people.canonical.com/%7Egavin/docs/lp:maas/install.html) and [Metal as a Service](http://www.greenhills.co.uk/2012/04/25/metal-as-a-service.html) will be more helpful to understand what MAAS is.

Comment: Thanks Nab for the response. Am I going to install KVM on the same server running MAAS? I guess one the KVM is installed, I should be able to install openstack to be able to control my nodes.

Comment: I've been able to fully configure MAAS and added my HP as a node and also installed both OpenStack and Juju on the same server. Though I can't seem to see my HP Hard Drives from OpenStack when I try NOVA to create volumes to load instances on, perhaps maybe because you need at least 6-9 node. But I should be able to see my node's hard drive from MAAS. In summary, how do I use OpenStack to create volumes and instances from my nodes that are being managed by MAAS? Do I have to make some changes to my NOVA config file?

Comment: I guess everyone is busy with their projects but a 2 or 3 line answer or response will help newbies like me to understand the MAAS and OpenStack Infrastructure and deployment. I don't want to keep creating new questions; I'll rather continue the thread in on page for other newbies like to be able to follow through.

Comment: You do not need MAAS for deploying OpenStack. Especially when you just started playing with it. There are a lot of OpenStack starting/deploying manuals for single or multi-node environment. Try [DevStack](http://devstack.org/) for simple All-in-One installation. It's a good choice for first time.

Comment: Nab, thanks for giving more tips on this. I've gone through DevStack just as I have looked at various OpenStack manuals. I think I'm pretty good now after looking into Kernel Virtualization, I realize how powerful OpenStack is and deployment with and without Juju worked perfectly.  I now fully understand the Ubuntu CloudInfrastructure at last. If I have any further questions in future, I will post.